# Inserting daily into firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have this activity where I need to insert data daily into the database but when inserting it daily it must not delete the previous days data so that means, I should be able to view all my data from the database in my app when I would like too. For example: the user must input their daily meals into the app which will update to the database but they would also like to view their meals that they input yesterday. How would i go about doing this using firebase database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to make something like this

```
 FirebaseFirestore
            .collection(YOUR_COLLECTION_NAME)
            .document(System.currentTimeMillis())// here comes the id of the document
            .set(YourMealObject(args...))
```

`System.currentTimeMillis()` should give you unique id's for your document

Comment: With implementing this, is it still possible to get all of the data from the database and display it in the app?

Comment: @Sileshan, yes, it is. To get all the data for collection it would be something like 
`FirebaseFirestore.collection(YOUR_COLLECTION_NAME)`

Answer (score 1):

For everytime you insert a data into the Firebase database , just create a random key , in that case it wont overide the previous value

```
    //get the push key value
String key = mDatabase.child("posts").push().getKey();

//then you can write in that node in this way
mDatabase.child("posts").child(key).setValue(yourValue)
```